# How can I use SQL functions in a NHibernate Update?

Tags: nhibernate

If certain conditions appear I want to set a field to the value of the MySQL function 
`NOW()`. The condition is determinable shortly before the update (for example `IInterceptor.OnSave` or `Session.SaveOrUpdate(myObj)`). This action should happen in the Update statement of NHibernate where other fields are updated as well.

The resulting SQL could be similar to this:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myStringCol = 'someVal', myDateCol = NOW() 
WHERE myId = 123;
```

The following constraints should be satisfied, but I will take every solution which is practicable:

- Querying `NOW()` before the update would flood the server with unnecessary requests
- Unfortunately it's not possible to use SPs or triggers
- It's not possible to use .Net DateTime.Now, it has to be the server time
- Because of the conditions it's not possible to use the default-value for a table column
- I know the possibility of custom SQL for create, update and delete (nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html 17.3), but how to implement the conditions?
- Using MySQL 5.1 / 5.5 / 5.6
- Using the latest NH 3.3.2

Comment: Can you explain what the conditions are, when are you checking for them?

Comment: The condition is determinable as soon as the object is ready to save or update (all properties setted and it is assured that the object is in a valid state). The conditions are not that easy to to explain and there are several cases. The distinction between the cases has to be done in .Net code.

Comment: Can't you then execute a different SQL against the database based on the condition then?

Comment: This is what I try todo. But how can I inject the sql-function NOW() into the NH generated SQL? The only way I found until now is IInterceptor.OnPrepareStatement. But this is pretty ugly because I have to parse SQL to understand what statements I have to manipulate. In the OnPrepareStatement i have no additional parameters that would allow to identify the case for which the SQL is used.

Comment: Have you tried executing literal SQL using NHibernate? You don't have to intercept anything, simply execute an SQL statement like the one you posted.

Comment: Executing raw SQL invalidates the cache of NH. Then there are many changes to many objects. Executing additional SQL update-statements for the date field only is not possible because of the data integrity. All the changes has to occur in one transaction. In my case the date-field is even in a composite unique index. This together with mysql (which does not implement deferred unique checks) means, that the changes need to occure in one sql-statement per object. So its not possible to led NH do things and afterwards execute a raw SQL-Update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generated properties for INSERT and UPDATE
Please refer to the documentation, Chapter 5
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated

Comment: This would be usefull if I would like to set the field to now() on insert and / or update, but it is not usefull if I need it only under certain conditions.

Comment: So, what's the difference from setting the value with DateTime.Now? I don't think it would make a difference in your case.

Comment: The difference is huge. DateTime.Now returns the client time which is not garanteed to be synchronized over all clients using the application. On the other hand the function NOW() returns the server time which is the same for all clients and not manipulable for the users.

Comment: Not really, if you are aware of the time zone of the server all the clients can report the same date value which is the one in use in the server. 
Btw, the only solution is to create an Interceptor that will contains or get the business logic to create the SQL statement using or not the NOW() function.

Comment: The software is running in more than 100 independent sites (one server per site), which are out of my control. I'm not able to ensure that date and time of the clients of one site are synchronised. The server time is the time I want.

Comment: So you have to stick with the interceptors